# Fluent NHibernate one of Primary Keys is also Foreign key - OutOfRangeException

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, foreign-keys, primary-key

```
Cart
{
 CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.CART_ID, "CART_ID").KeyProperty(x => x.COMM_CD, "COMM_CD");
 References(x => x.Product, "COMM_CD");
}
```

When I tried to save cart object into database I received out of range exception. I think it's because I have two COMM_CD properties. Is there a way to solve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `KeyReference` instead of `KeyProperty`

```
CompositeId()
    .KeyProperty(x => x.CART_ID, "CART_ID")
    .KeyReference(x => x.Product, "COMM_CD");
```